# Idea/Intuition behind using commutator of light cone number operator and BRST generator

Tags: string-theory, commutator, brst

In ch-$4$ of Polchinksi while proving no-ghost theorem we are introduced to number operator of light cone oscillators
$$N^{lc}=\sum_m{\frac{1}{m}:\alpha^+_{-m}\alpha^-_m:}\tag{4.4.6}$$
$$\alpha^{\pm}_m=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\alpha^0_m\pm\alpha^1_m)$$
Then we decompose $Q_B$ according to $N^{lc}$ as $$Q_B=Q_1+Q_0+Q_{-1}$$ with each operator satisfying certian commutation relation with $N^{lc}$ and $N^g$. This certain use of commutation relation has no obvious explanation, at least to me, since we're working with compact fields as well so I'm not sure if general formula $Q_B=c^I(G^m_I+\frac{1}{2}G^g_I)$ works here and the commutaor of $Q_B$ and $N^{lc}$ are assumed rather than derived so this assumption is keypoint in this derivation which I can't motivate in any way. What is going on here?